# Unable to call a function from within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and trying to debug a script that will hopefully allow the user to select multiple rows of a table using Shift+Click and set the checkboxes to selected. I found an example online and I'm trying to debug the code, but I'm getting to line where a function is called, but the function never gets entered. I'm not sure why?

Here is the script:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {

    if(j$) {
        //alert('Jquery loaded successfully...');
    }
    console.log(j$('input[id$=btnSearch]'));
    j$('input[id$=btnSearch]').click(function(){
        console.log(j$('[id$=searchTable] > tbody tr'));
        var trs = j$('[id$=searchTable] > tbody tr');
        j$('tr').on('click', function(myEvent){
            //call the RowClick function on click event
            RowClick(j$(this),false,trs,myEvent)
        })
    });     
});

//declare variable to store the most recently clicked row
var lastSelectedRow;

// disable text selection
document.onselectstart = function() {
    return false;
}

function RowClick(currentrow, lock, rows, myEvent) {
    console.log('******************************************* we are inside the RowClick function');
    console.log(currentrow);
    console.log(lock);
    console.log(rows);
    console.log(myEvent);
    //if control is held down, toggle the row
    if (myEvent.ctrlKey) {
        toggleRow(currentrow);
    }

    //if there are no buttons held down...
    if (myEvent.button === 0) {

        //if neither control or shift are held down...
        if (!myEvent.ctrlKey && !myEvent.shiftKey) {
            //clear selection
            clearAll(rows);
            //toggle clicked row
            toggleRow(currentrow);
        }

        //if shift is held down...
        if (myEvent.shiftKey) {
            console.log('************************************** we are in the shift key branch');
            console.log(currentrow);
            console.log(currentrow.index());
            console.log(rows);
            console.log('************************************** we are calling the toggleRow function');
            toggleRow(currentrow);
            console.log('************************************** we have called the toggleRow function');
            //pass the indexes of the last selected row and currently selected row along with all rows
            selectRowsBetweenIndexes([lastSelectedRow.index(), currentrow.index()], rows)
        }
    }
}

function toggleRow(row) {
    console.log('******************************* we are inside the toggleRow function');
    console.log(row);
    if (!row.hasClass('header-row')){
        console.log('****************************** we are inside the row does not have the header-row class');
        lastSelectedRow = row.toggleClass('selected');
    }
}

function selectRowsBetweenIndexes(indexes,rows) {
    //sort the indexes in ascending order
    indexes.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    //for every row starting at the first index, until the second index...
    for (var i = indexes[0]; i <= indexes[1]; i++) {
        //select the row
        j$(rows[i+1]).addClass('selected');
    }
}

function clearAll(rows) {
    j$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
}
```

I get to this line:

`console.log('************************************** we are calling the toggleRow function');`

and the next line output is this line:

`console.log('************************************** we have called the toggleRow function');`

The toggleRow function is never entered. I'm new to jquery and unclear if I'm calling the function incorrectly? Or, why I'm not seeing the output of lines showing that I've entered the toggleRow function?

Comment: A couple of things, it's a good idea to pair down the code you're posting to a minimum verifiable example. You have a large chunk there which is probably partially why you haven't had a lot of response to your question. Can you provide us with the output of your console.log(currentrow) and check if you have any console errors?

Comment: @RyanGibbs Thanks for your reply. I think part of the issue is the click event on the table row is not selecting the correct table rows. It is selecting any table row instead of the specific row of the table that has the results. Here is output for the table: [link](https://imgur.com/a/JdxJZzr). How would I select the correct table row element for the click event for that table? Instead of `j$('tr').on('click',...`

Comment: I would use j$(document).on('click', 'tr', ... So that the event listener will see any dynamically added content, then in your callback function, use the 'this' keyword as it would refer to the specific tr clicked.